# exclusão de elemento de uma coluna em um dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```
 Município (Código)                  Município  Valor
2            1100015 Alta Floresta D'Oeste - RO 408765
3            1100023             Ariquemes - RO 477322
4            1100031                Cabixi - RO 126630
5            1100049                Cacoal - RO 463570
6            1100056            Cerejeiras - RO  96654
7            1100064     Colorado do Oeste - RO 266464
```

e preciso excluir as UFs da coluna de Municípios, portanto, preciso que meu dataframe fique assim:

```
 Município (Código)            Município        Valor
2            1100015  Alta Floresta D'Oeste     408765
3            1100023             Ariquemes      477322
4            1100031                Cabixi      126630
5            1100049                Cacoal      463570
6            1100056            Cerejeiras      96654
7            1100064     Colorado do Oeste      266464
```

Como faço para fazer esse tipo de manipulação no R?